# JS: Call a specific function of a given script-object

Tags: javascript, dom, call, highslide

**Is this possible?**

```
myscripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
myscripts[0].init();
```

**The Problem**

i use highslide with several html-Windows (htmlExpand). Every have a script with a init()function.
If one Window is opened, it's included init function should be called.

Because, there are now several init functions, i couldn't call it directly, because it call in most cases the wrong function.

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterExpand = function (sender) {init()}
```

i have to call a function of a given script object

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterExpand = function (sender) {
  var content = this.content.getElementsByClassName("highslide-maincontent")[0];
  var myscripts = content.getElementsByTagName("script");
  for (var i = 0; i < myscripts.length; i ++){
     if (typeof myscripts[i].init == "function"){
        myscripts[i].init();
   }
}
```

But how i could do it? This shouln't work.

```
myscripts[i].init();
```

So, how i could call a function of a given script-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible, because an [`HTMLScriptElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement), returned by `document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]` in your code block, does not have an `init()` method. Indeed it doesn't have *any* methods, nor does it inherit `init()` from its parents up the chain [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), or [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget).

I think you are trying to expose the `init()` method on whatever JS objects are added in a particular script. But, you wouldn't do it that way. For that, you might want to look into something like: https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/